# ArangoDB cluster low traversal query performance

Tags: arangodb

Recently we moved our product from ArangoDB single node to ArangoDB cluster mode (version 3.3.9). 
As a result we are experiencing much longer query times.
The above query is returning data on the single node ArangoDB within a few milliseconds:

```
WITH Node_Collection_1
FOR c IN Node_Collection_1


LET neighbours = (FOR v,e,p IN INBOUND c._id 
Edge_Collection_1
RETURN v._key
)

return {
    content: c._key,
    neighbours: neighbours
}
```

On the clustered ArangoDB the same query on the same data is taking a few seconds (~15 seconds).

In our use case we have many small graphs (1 node collection and 1 edge collection per graph) and therefore we configured each collection to have only one shard since each graph won't be too large. 
The cluster configuration is:

- 3 data nodes
- 3 agent nodes
- 1 coordinator node

All of them are distributed among 3 AWS machines on top of Kubernetes.

Assuming that both the Node_collection_1 and Edge_collection_1 are happened to be on the same data node, why there is a so drastic latency degradation compared to the single node setup? And what can be done in order to improve this?

Comment: What is the replication factor of the collections? What does the execution plan look like? Is every pair of node and edge collection actually on the same DBserver? Can you try 3.4-RC1 for comparison?

Comment: If Node_Collection_1 is huge and on a different node than the edge collection, then there will be many network roundtrips, which would explain the increase in query duration. If you could upgrade to the latest 3.3 release and run https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/Manual/Programs/Arangoinspect/ that would help to debug the issue. There might be a way in Enterprise Edition using SmartGraphs to ensure the shards of each collection pair are on the same node for a local traversal. Feel free to create a GitHub ticket, which is a better place for such questions.

Comment: @CoDEmanX the replication factor is 1 (only main replica without followers),
both collections are on the same data node, the size of Node_collection_1 is 27.9MB and it has 12,559 docs. Is it considered huge?